# Bash commands are ignored in my ENTRYPOINT Docker bash script

Tags: bash, docker

I have some few libraries that I have compiled on my machine. So I want to copy all the binaries into my docker container and at first, I tried to use `COPY` and `ADD` command in my `Dockerfile`:

```
# Installing zeromq
WORKDIR /${home}/${user}/master-wheel
COPY ${PWD}/libzmq ./libzmq
COPY ${PWD}/cppzmq ./cppzmq
WORKDIR /${home}/${user}/master-wheel/libzmq/binaries
ADD * /
WORKDIR /${home}/${user}/master-wheel/cppzmq/binaries
ADD * /
```

Note that the directories and files do exist and upon entering into my created container, I can see that the copied directories `libzmq` and `cppzmq` do exist and I can manually copy all the binaries to the root `/`. However, for some reason Dockerfile doesn't copy and I can't figure out what could be the problem.

Then, I have decided to do that inside my `ENTRYPOINT` script and it looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -e
#set -u

echo "==> Executing master image entrypoint ..."

echo "-> Setting up"
cp -r /home/ed/master-wheel/libzmq/binaries/* /
cp -r /home/ed/master-wheel/cppzmq/binaries/* /
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib
ldconfig

echo "==> Container ready"
exec "$@"
```

Everything except two `cp` commands executes. I tried the same command (`cp` command) from my container bash terminal and it worked.

What could be the problem?

EDIT:

This part of the file works and the binaries do really get copied to the root directory:

```
# Installing libfreespace
WORKDIR /${home}/${user}/master-wheel
COPY ${PWD}/libfreespace ./libfreespace
WORKDIR /${home}/${user}/master-wheel/libfreespace/binaries
COPY * /
```

EDIT 2:

It seems that if I do something like this:

```
WORKDIR /${home}/${user}/master-wheel
COPY ${PWD}/libzmq ./libzmq
COPY ${PWD}/cppzmq ./cppzmq
WORKDIR /${home}/${user}/master-wheel/libzmq/binaries/usr/
ADD * /usr/
WORKDIR /${home}/${user}/master-wheel/cppzmq/binaries/usr/
ADD * /usr/
```

It works.

Comment: You're mixing container paths and host paths: the only thing in this setup that refers to host paths are the first argument to `COPY` and `ADD`.  Your two `ADD * /` lines are identical, and both copy the entire content of the `docker build` context directory into the image's root directory.

Comment: (Your `WORKDIR` and `cd` commands change paths inside the container and can't see things in the corresponding host paths.)

Comment: @DavidMaze I totally agree with you and what you said does make a sense but look at my edit, how that part worked even though it is almost identical

Comment: Understanding the layout of your context directory would be helpful.  If you look inside your built image, I sort of would expect to see an extra `/libfreespace/libfreespace` binary and some totally empty directories named things like `/master-wheel`.

Comment: @DavidMaze Ok, I will have a look but after some research, other people successfully copied their files into the root, for example:
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25925

What would be your suggestion? How to copy binaries into /usr/local/lib for example?